# Error: Could not find or load main class - .jar file execution

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable, executable-jar

I've been digging and digging trying everything I can to resolve this but nothing seems to be working. I just installed Intellij IDEA on my machine and created a new maven project. I am simply attempting to execute a hello world program to verify everything is setup correctly. However, something is not right.

When running the application in IDEA I receive "Hello World" as expected. However when running maven package and generating a .jar file, when I attempt to execute that .jar file I receive the following message:

```
C:\dev\lwjglplayground\target>java lwjgl-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class lwjgl-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: lwjgl-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

My first instinct was that I had botched something in my java installation (as right before installing IDEA I removed my java 8 jdk and installed jdk 11), but I verified that other .jar files which I had previously built execute as expected.

My `pom.xml` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>whitwhoa</groupId>
    <artifactId>lwjgl-playground</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <start-class>whitwhoa.Main</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>whitwhoa.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>whitwhoa.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

This is my `Main.java` file:

```
package whitwhoa;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }

}
```

Does anything here stick out to anyone as being misconfigured? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the `-jar` parameter as a command line argument:

```
java -jar lwjgl-playground-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: You've gotta be kidding me! That definitely took care of it. Would you happen to know why other .jar files I have do not require this? Is there something I can add to the maven build process that would allow execution without strictly adding this flag?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, I always use `-jar` when starting up jar files? I wasn't aware you could just call `java <jar>` -- if someone else can answer this feel free to update my answer with some context as to why the `-jar` parameter is explicitly required for this one

Comment: Well...turns out that the .jar WAS being executed when double clicked. However, no command line opened to display the "Hello World" text (or opened and closed so fast that it was not visible). I had a hunch this is what was happening, so I updated the main function to save a file to the directory where the .jar is located...double clicked...there's my file. Apologies for any confusion I may have caused.